# Paquete ETL (ssis) no carga excel de 179 mil registros

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

He construido un paquete ETL la cual carga datos desde un excel 2010 (179 mil registros) hacia una tabla en una base de datos (construcción simple, carga directa).

En mi trabajo se cuenta con tres ambientes (Desarrollo, Calidad y Producción), mi construcción en el ambiente de desarrollo carga en su totalidad a través de Jobs (Paquete y configs) y a nivel proyecto (Visual Studio 2013).

En el ambiente de calidad, de las mismas características que desarrollo y producción, el Job también carga en su totalidad el excel; pero en el ambiente de producción con las mismas características de los dos ambientes mencionados anteriormente no carga data del excel y me indica el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Considerar: `GESTION_WT_VC` (Nombre de archivo excel) / Detalle (Nombre de hoja) / Peso del archivo excel: 31 MB aprox / Cantidad de registros: 179 mil registros.
- Descartes realizados en el ambiente de producción:

  - Cambiar de hoja de con la misma cantidad de data (mismo error).
  - Reducir la cantidad de data a 50 mil registros (mismo error).
  - El paquete contiene flujos 18 cargas de excel con 2 mil registros aprox. cada uno y se carga satisfactoriamente a excepción de `GESTION_WT_VC` (Es el excel mas pesado).
- Lo último que hice con el archivo excel fue reducir la data hasta 5000 registros y se ejecuto el Job, obteniedo una respuesta positiva de carga.

No se que podría estar pasando en el ambiente de producción que no permite cargar el archivo excel con 179 mil registros. Quedo atento a sus comentarios, gracias.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 4):

Vamos por partes:

`VS_ISBROKEN` indica que el componente tiene un error que puede ser solucionando el componente en el diseñador. Este error es típicamente causado por una propiedad personalizada o requiere una conexión que no está especificada o está definida incorrectamente. Quizás tengas algún valor numérico y por algún lado exista un caracter de espaciado.

> One or more compontent failed validation

Aquí la solución es sencilla:

```
Set DelayValidation = True  //En el administrador de conexiones y en el data flow.
```

El siguiente error:

> There were errors during task validation

Esto se debe a un mapeo de columna, revisa si no hay campos nullos en el destino.

En las propiedades del proyecto **RUN64bits to FALSE**.

Esto se pone interesante:

> SSIS error code dts_e_oledberror. an ole db error has occurred. error code  0x80004005

**Causa:**

El dueño del job determina el contexto de la seguridad en el cual el job se ejecuta. Si el job es adueñado (owned) por una cuenta de SQL Server Login que no es un miembro de "Sysadmin fixed server role", el paquete SSIS se ejecuta en el contexto de "SQL Server Agent proxy account"

Si deseas que "SQL Server Agent proxy account" ejecuta los jobs que conectan a una instancia de SQL Server, el SQL Server Agent proxy account tiene que tener los permisos correctos de la instancia del SQL Server.

**Solución:**

Tienes que cambiar los permisos para el directorio Temp del SQL Server Agent Service startup account. Otorgar permisos de lectura y escritura al SQL Server Agent Proxy account para este directorio.

Lo del "Rowset" me late que es por alguna llave foránea que es inexistente.

Espero te sea de utilidad hermano, que tengas un buen día, eleva el cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, de donde sacas las referencias para entender los errores?, gracias.

Comment: saludos hermano, bueno, digamos que es una mezcla de experiencia y buena suerte en internet, me explico: hay un buscador en particular que utilizo: https://ecosia.org aprovecho para plantar arbolitos en nuestro planeta mientras busco por internet, úsalo por favor y recomiéndalo, necesitamos reparar nuestro planeta Tierra. En la parte del error, en "Message", copias,pegas, y le das forma a la búsqueda; por ejemplo en el caso de "GESTION_WT_VC", como es un campo en exclusivo de esa base de datos, lo omites. De toda la información que encuentres en algún idioma, lo traduces, ¡y listo!  De nada :D

Comment: jajaja, esperaba una respuesta más seria, no lo tomes a mal, pero la mayoría mensajes de error tienen significado bastante genérico, o dan una orientación ambigua, al menos quisiera tener una referencia oficial de que quieren decir. Luego, por poner un ejemplo, el colocar set delayvalidation en true, al tratar de un error en tiempo de ejecución y no de diseño no implicaría arreglar "el error", pues la validación debe pasar "limpia" siempre que tenga la data correcto, en otras palabras cambiar el valor no omitirá el error en sí, solo el mensaje.

Comment: Ya veo que contestaste básicamente traduciendo lo que encontraste sin llegar a estar seguro de si el error es o no, pues claro, no tienes el escenario preciso (en realidad sí el post es muy bueno)

Comment: "esperaba una respuesta más seria", ¿Qué elementos consideras que tiene una respuesta más seria? Si buscadores hay de todo tipo, mi favorito es https://ecosia.org como quien vamos plantando arbolitos mientras buscamos :D,  "la mayoría mensajes de error tienen significado bastante genérico, o dan una orientación ambigua", depende del error y de la interpretación de la persona con el inglés . "contestaste básicamente traduciendo lo que encontraste sin llegar a estar seguro de si el error es o no" discrepo este punto.

Comment: Gracias por la sinceridad, la valoro mucho :D lo que dices tiene mucho sentido, ten en mente que también hay experiencia de por medio, si no la hubiera, dudo que me haya animado a responder la pregunta. Las limitantes que existen son bastante claras: Inexistencia del excel, esquema de la tabla, jobs, usuarios, permisos en el server, entre otros. Finalmente hermano, no, no lo he tomado a mal, nunca lo hago, siempre ando en modo escucha, en este caso, en modo lectura :D un abrazo